# Minimizing Coulomb potential of two electrons in non-degenerate state of a harmonic oscillator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, harmonic-oscillator

Suppose you have a non degenerate state at harmonic oscillator. How will you distribute 2 electrons such that the coulomb potential will be minimum?

Comment: What is your Hamiltonian of the system?

Comment: @KP99 I think that Hamiltonian is the same as that of a harmonic oscillator and there is another interaction energy term that only depends inversely on their separation between them i.e.(rij)

Comment: Okay. The potential for the system will be of the form:$V=(1/2)kr^2+(1/r)+l(l+1)/2r^2$. Equilibrium point should satisfy $dV/dr=0$. Now, if you want to minimize only Coulombic potential, you can simply consider $r\to\infty$. See this article: https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0953-4075/36/22/009/pdf

Answer (score 0):

The potential energy is the integral of the repulsive force times the displacement (in this case of one of the electrons moving away from the other). That is equal to the total work that can be done by the electron. And the coulomb force is inversely proportional the square of their separation distance, meaning you want to maximize that.

Put them infinitely far from each other, or as far as possible.